# Generic: Is there a way to make compiler check T is a particular UIView subclass?

Tags: ios, swift, generics, uikit

Currently, I have the following handy generic function, which enables me to create custom view from XIB

```
extension UIView {
    static func instanceFromNib<T: UIView>() -> T {
        return UINib(nibName: String(describing: self), bundle: nil).instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil)[0] as! T
    }
}
```

---

The usage is

```
let colorPickerView: ColorPickerView
// Returned type from ColorPickerView.instanceFromNib is UIView, not ColorPickerView.
colorPickerView = ColorPickerView.instanceFromNib()
```

However, compiler is only able to know returned value from `ColorPickerView.instanceFromNib` is `UIView`. It doesn't know the returned value from `ColorPickerView.instanceFromNib` is in fact `ColorPickerView`.

The following code will compile without issue, but causing runtime error.

```
let colorPickerView: UIButton  // UIButton is child of UIView.
// Returned type from ColorPickerView.instanceFromNib is UIView, not ColorPickerView.
colorPickerView = ColorPickerView.instanceFromNib()
```

---

I was wondering, is there a way to further improve the above generic function, so that we can

```
// No issue. Returned type from CustomView1.instanceFromNib is CustomView1. 
let customView1: CustomView1 = CustomView1.instanceFromNib()

// No issue. Returned type from CustomView2.instanceFromNib is CustomView2. 
let customView2: CustomView2 = CustomView2.instanceFromNib()

// Compile error. Compiler knows the returned type is CustomView1.
let customView3: CustomView3 = CustomView1.instanceFromNib()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can improve this so the above code would fail, but it can never be certain that it has the right type.

To handle the above code, you just need to change `instanceFromNib()` to return Self, rather than "whatever type the caller requests."

```
static func instanceFromNib() -> Self {
    UINib(nibName: String(describing: self), bundle: nil)
        .instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil)[0] as! Self
}
```

But it's still possible for that NIB to hold the wrong type, and that wouldn't be discovered until runtime because you have to load the data from the file to know.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Looks solid. Didn't realise there is a `Self` besides `self`.